# Passing structs as output parameters in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

What is the best practice for passing structures as an output in C++11?

Should the struct be created in the outer function or the inner when the ownership is to be maintained by the outer function?

And, should it be a shared_ptr or unique_ptr?

For example, suppose I have a complex struct along the lines of:

```
struct Error {
    string Code;
    string Message;
    string Details;
    string Command;
};

struct Response {
    stringstream Data;
    bool Success;
    Error Error;
};
```

Then, from the calling function, I want to state:

```
Response r;
getResponse( url, &r );
```

Should getResponse be defined as:

```
getResponse( string, shared_ptr );    or
getResponse( string, unique_ptr );
```

Also, how should the strings, and stringstreams be declared?  Should they also be shared_ptr?

In this case, the getResponse function does not want anything to do with the response once it is done, and the lifetime of the response itself should be up to the caller.

What is the best practice for declaring and populating the struct?

Comment: None of this is very C++11-like.  Simply return your objects by value.

Comment: Do you really have to pass `Response` as a parameter? It seems you can have just `Response getResponse(url);`

Comment: Agreed, I could return it....but I have cases where I have several outputs and success codes in other functions.    I was trying to keep uniformity amongst the API without defining a ton of structs or classes for the return types.

Comment: @user3072517 your function can effectively have multiple return values by making the return type be `std::tuple<Resp1, Otherstuff, Morestuff>` .

Comment: Herb Sutter did a gotw entry on the generalized form of this problem (for which you will find that his answer aligns with those here on SO). I highly recommend giving it (and the other gotw's) a read: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/

Comment: Mark.   That is what I was looking for!   It describes they whys, not just how.   And in my case, my function is a source factory, so unique_ptr is what Herb indicates is the best answer.  Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 8):

Modern compilers are very good at optimizing how values are returned from functions so it is common to return by value when that makes sense:

```
// Just return by value
Response getResponse(const std::string& url)
{
    Response r;

    // ...

    return r;
}
```

Comment: BTW:  Response as a return value cannot be done because of stringstream in the struct is not copyable.   unique_ptr<Response> is what it needs to be.

Comment: @user3072517: actually, any half-decent compiler should be able to **move r**, so a stringstream being not copyable is irrelevant…

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on the fact that I can't do a copy of the data, having a return type of Response will not work in my situation.

It seems that I have two choices:

```
int getResponse( const std::string &url, shared_ptr<Response> )
```

or

```
unique_ptr<Response> getResponse( const std::string &url )
```

So it becomes in code:

```
if( !getResponse( "http://...", response ) )
   // report error
```

as opposed to

```
if( getResponse( "http://..." ) == nullptr )
   // report error
```

In terms of coding patterns/best practice, which is preferable?

The advantage that I with the second one, is that I can check the results without having to look at nullptr.

Comment: Just because something is not copyable doesn't mean you can't use it as a return type. `unique_ptr` is not copyable either.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, Galik's answer is right, just return by value. Then both your approaches are **wrong**, clearly. You have an object in the stack, that object's lifetime is perfectly managed by the compiler and you cannot `delete` the object (or use a smart pointer to `delete` it).

If you have some special interest in not returning by value (maybe the object is reused in a tight loop and you would like to have the string buffers reused… most probably not the case, but bear with me), I would suggest that you use a *reference* for the argument or a *pointer*:

```
void getResponse(std::string const& url, Response& resp);
void getResponse(std::string const& url, Response* resp);
```

The first is clearer in that the second argument is not optional, and there is no need to test or worry about it potentially being null. On the other hand, certain coding conventions require the second form as it might be clearer from the caller's side that the function will modify the object (in the call `getResponse(url, &response)` the `url` argument won't be modified, the `response` may (`&`). This is for example the case of Google's coding style.  Personally I prefer reference, but you know… when in Rome… if your shop has a policy just follow it.

Comment: So, you touched on one of the points that I was a bit concerned about...the stack.   This is an object which is going to hold a lot of data, and what I cannot afford is a memory allocation/copy to occur.   If the stack is only copying the struct by pointer value, then fine with the return object.

The other point of passing out parameters was because this is actually part of a managed & unmanaged wrapper dll & lib.   The ideal situation would be to go from managed to unmanaged and back again via pointers, but because of GC, I am forced to do a copy.   I don't want any more.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly difference answer to why you should return by value here is the contents of your structs.  If the contents of your objects are cheap to move then you should return by value. Move semantics will kick-in automatically because the compiler knows the local scope object you are returning is about to be destroyed.

If your object is not cheap move/copy, I'd say the classic advice of pass by ref/pointer is still applicable.  unique_ptr/shared_ptr should only come into play when object ownership is being addressed.  ie.  I'm passing this object to a function and that function owns it now.  If ownership isn't being changed use the classic advice of pass by ref and pointer.

Comment: So in my case, where it has the potential for a lot of data, should I revert back to passing in a pointer?   Also, the other trouble I had with returning an object is how then do you detect if an error condition occurs during the creating of that object.   I want to avoid a throw at this point, because they are so expensive.

Comment: Its safe to use raw pointers and reference as long as they are not owning pointers and references.  ie.  if at some point you need to call delete on it.  The delete call should be handled by a smart pointer (unique_ptr / shared_ptr).  Or an hand rolled RAII class that handles your resource management.